# How to handle huge data with QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: c++, qt

We have a QSqlQueryModel which loads huge chunk of data. When its size of loaded data reaches to about 1.5 GB, the program crashes. How can we handle this situation? Can we catch an exception or limit the amount of data that QSqlQueryModel loads?

Comment: Is this a 32 bit application on windows? If so you are most likely running out of address space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code is running on PC hardware, you could always try using 64-bit executable instead of 32-bit.

On the other hand, it's unlikely that you actually WANT 1.5GB of data from the database - I mean, certainly no human will search through such a huge amount, and if you are using a database to find things, you shouldn't need to "filter later" or some such, then you are "doing it wrong".

Limiting the "search results" by for example by using `SELECT x, y FROM tablename LIMIT n,m` (where `n` is the "first element" and `m` is the number of elements you want to fetch. If you limit the number of elements to a reasonable number, even if your actual data is very large.

I doubt very much that "catching the exception" is a particularly meaningful idea, because the problem is really that you are "fetching huge amounts of data from the database", which I'd say is wrong every time it happens.